# In networkx python, how to connect a new bunch of nodes and edges to each node in a graph?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, power-law

Currently I created a graph as follow:

```
import networkx as nx
edges = []
for i in range (10):
    edges.append((i,i+1))
edges += [(10,0), (1,10), (2,8), (3,7), (4,6), (4,10), (5,10)]
# create the graph
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([i for i in range (11)])
G.add_edges_from(edges)
```

Now what I need is to connect a random number of new nodes to each node of the above core network, according to a power law distribution with  =3.
So I got a new graph with power law distribution (for example: of 15 nodes):

```
s1 = nx.utils.powerlaw_sequence(15, 3) #15 nodes, power-law exponent 3
G1 = nx.expected_degree_graph(s1, selfloops=False)
```

Now how can I connect this new graph to a certain node in my previous network? Tried `add_nodes_from` but they seem to overwrite previous nodes, which is odd; and I can't make sure they're connected to a certain node. Or is there any straightforward way to do this? Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Could you please provide the expected output? I know it's random, but just make an example please :)

Comment: new nodes needs new numbers/values - if you add again `[i for i in range(11)]` then it replaces them. If you add `[i for i in range(11, 13)]` then it will add new nodes - `11,12`. Maybe create nodes with unique values - ie. `(uniq_number, value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that `nx.expected_degree_graph` creates a graph whose nodes have labels 0 ... 14. If you try to join `G` and `G1`, nodes with the same name are merged.

You need `G1` to have nodes with unique labels. You can achieve such result by using the [relabel_nodes](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.relabel.relabel_nodes.html#networkx.relabel.relabel_nodes) function:

```
relabel_dict = {node: node+len(G.nodes) for node in G1.nodes}
G1 = nx.relabel_nodes(G1, relabel_dict)
```

Now you can safely join `G` and `G1` by using the [compose](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.operators.binary.compose.html) function:

```
new_G = nx.compose(G, G1)
```